# Subgroup of invertible matrices proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For this pertinent question I will attach both the written text format as instructed as well as my solution and also the question attached as images if that is easier to view.

[image]

[image]

The written question as requested:

Let T be the set of matrices:
T = ( cos u sin u   0   0)
    ( -sin u    cos u   0   0)
    ( 0 0   1   t)
    (0  0   0   1)

Given that u is an element of the real numbers.

Show that T is a subgroup of the group of invertible matrices under matrix multiplication.

This is a new area that I am delving into so I am in unfamiliar territory any responses would be great.

-nomad609

Comment: Your text contradicts your scans. On the first photo, it says that $u\in\mathbb{R}$, which is all reals, not rationals.

Comment: Sorry it should really be real numbers. Yes you are correct. NOT rationals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\det (t)=1$ then $t$ is invertible and $\det(t^{-1})=1.$ In this Q you must also show that $t^{-1}$ has the same form as $t,$ and that if $t_1,t_2$ have that form then so does their product $t_1t_2.$ Hint: $T$ (as you have written it ) is a function of $u,$ so write $T(u)$ instead of $T.$ Then what is $T(u)T(-u)$ and what is $T(u_1)T(u_2)$?

If $G$ is a group and $\emptyset \ne H\subset G,$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff (i)$\;h^{-1}\in H$ whenever $h\in H,$ and (ii) $\;h_1h_2\in H$ whenever $h_1$ and $h_2$ belong to $H.$

Comment: Thank you this makes it a lot clearer. T(u)T(-u) = 1 and then for your second question I have that as (U1*U2)(T)

Answer (score 2):

To show it's a subgroup, show that it is closed under multiplication and inverse, i.e. the product of any two elements of $T$ is in $T$, and the inverse of any element of $T$ is in $T$.

The addition formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ will be useful here.